# MongoDB java-driver-3.2.2 count results from find()-method

Tags: java, mongodb, count, find, mongodb-java

I am trying to count the results of a `find()` method, but it doesn´t work. I am using the `mongodb-driver-3.2.2` and `mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2` for JAVA.

This is the code I am using to connect to the MongoDB

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("database_name");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection_name");
```

I search in the MongoDb with this code:

```
collection.find(eq("status", 1));
```

The method ".count()" work only for the whole collection, like this:

```
long a = collection.count();
```

But when i try to us it in combination with the `find()` method, it doesn´t work:

```
long a = collection.find(eq("status", 1)).count();
```

Error:

```
The method count() is undefined for the type FindIterable<Document>
```

So, my solution is:

```
long a = 0;
FindIterable<Document> results = collection.find(eq("status", 1));
for (Document current : results ) {
    a++;
}
```

I DON´T like this solution. Is there a other solution to count the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count is a method on the collection object, not on the FindIterable. It takes the filter as an optional parameter, so to stay in the Filters-world:

```
collection.count(eq("status", 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
collection.count(new Document().append("status",1));
```